# "The item provided is not valid" azure mobile services invokeAPI call to backend

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Services in my iOS app hooked up to my backend. What I'm trying to do is upload an image to my backend as multipart/form-data.

I have done the following:

1. Create a "body" as NSMutableData with the multipart/form-data in it (including my image data to be uploaded)

   ```
       let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

       let body = NSMutableData()

       let fname = "test.png"
       let mimetype = "image/png"

       //define rest of multipart/form-data with image data embedded

       body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
       body.appendData("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
       body.appendData("hi\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



       body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
       body.appendData("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
       body.appendData("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
       body.appendData(image_data)
       body.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

       body.appendData("--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
   ```
2. Upload the data to my api-end point using .invokeAPI (custom api calls)

   ```
       Azure.client.invokeAPI("UploadProfileImage", body: body, HTTPMethod: "POST", parameters: nil, headers: ["Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"]) { (result, response, error) -> Void in
           if error == nil {
               print("SUCCESs! wOO")
               print(result)
           }else{
               print("ERROR!: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
               print("response: \(response)")
               print("result: \(result)")
           }
       }
   ```

*The "boundary" variable is being received from this func:

```
func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
}
```

However **the error I keep getting is "The item provided is not valid"**. This is driving me crazy as I'm sure my multipart/form-data is correct and that I'm uploading it in the right way, I just don't understand why it won't accept the data.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The error is from the backend.  Does your backend support multipart/form-data?  Note that the Azure Mobile Apps backend does not support multipart/form-data out of the box - you generally have to create an standard ASP.NET or Node.js/Express API to handle these situations.

Comment: @AdrianHall yes my backend does support multipart/form-data. we managed to upload an image from the web to the backend, but the struggle is on iOS right now...

Comment: Can you provide more details on the error, such as a stack trace? Can you provide the backend code for the API?

Comment: @SwedishiOS did you get any solution regarding this?